# One code - logging for both platforms - android / windows

Tags: java, android, generics, logging

is there a simple way to used the same code basis for:

1. logging into android using `android.util.Log` (to get logging into Logcat)
   and for another compile **but with the same code** (in some generic approach) to
2. log into another Log-Framework for the Windows platform?

Something like:

`genericlog.i("myinfo")` --> translates on android into: `Log.i("myinfo")` //for logcat

and for win compile

`genericlog.i("myinfo")` --> translates on window into: `whatever-log-framework.info("myinfo")` is configured :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, my solution was to use https://github.com/MicroUtils/kotlin-logging.

Dependencies for android

```
    implementation 'io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging:2.0.4'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.7.21'
```

Dependencies for windows

```
    implementation("io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging-jvm:2.0.2")
    implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30")
```

And with this I could use same logging structure in "common" code.

```
private val log = KotlinLogging.logger {}
log.info{"log it :-)"}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the use of [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/android/) will be a good solution. SLF4J is available on both usual JVM and also on Android.

If you want to use SLF4J with Logback, you will find [here](https://www.triology.de/en/blog-entries/slf4j-and-logback-android) a hands on.